# Why does the BET equation take into consideration a multimolecular-layer, even though it deals with chemisorption?

Tags: surface-chemistry, adsorption

I came across the Brunauer-Emmet-Teller (BET) equation recently, and one thing that I found strange was an implicit reference to the formation of molecular multi-layer.

In the [BET equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BET_theory)

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{P}{V(P^0 - P)} &= \frac{1}{CV_m} + \frac{C-1}{CV_m}\cdot \frac{P}{P^0}\, ; \tag{1}\\
C &= e^{(Q_1 - Q_2)/RT}\quad (C:\text{constant})\, ,\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

where $V_m$ – monolayer adsorption amount, V – adsorption amount at the equilibrium pressure $P$, $Q_\mathrm{L}$ refers to the heat of adsorption of the second and higher layers of adsorbate onto the adsorbent.

Now according to my textbook, chemisorption only results in the formation of a molecular monolayer. Multilayers are formed by physisorption.

The thing is, I'm told the BET equation is an extension of Langmuir's adsorption isotherm for *chemisorption* at low pressures. If the BET equation applies only to chemisorption, then what is the point of including a term dependent on the formation of *multilayers*, when chemisorption *doesn't* even form a multilayer all by itself.

Is there something I'm overlooking here? The internet has *not* yielded any decent result in that regard.

Comment: BET equation does not deal with chemisorption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brunauer–Emmett–Teller (BET) explains the **physical adsorption** of gas molecules on a solid surface, and doesn't address **chemisorption**. Even the wikipedia link that you provided, makes that quite explicit. However, you are correct to think that it is in a extension of the Langmuir adsorption model, which only accounts for monolayers.

The assumption that underscore this model are as follows:

> 1. Adsorptions occur only on well-defined sites of the sample surface (one per molecule)
> 2. The only molecular interaction considered is the following one: a molecule can act as a single adsorption site for a molecule of the upper layer.
> 3. The uppermost molecule layer is in equilibrium with the gas phase, i.e. similar molecule adsorption and desorption rates.
> 4. The desorption is a kinetically-limited process, i.e. a heat of adsorption must be provided:
>
>    - these phenomenon are homogeneous, i.e. same heat of adsorption for a given molecule layer.
>    - it is E1 for the first layer, i.e. the heat of adsorption at the solid sample surface
>    - the other layers are assumed similar and can be represented as condensed species, i.e. liquid state. Hence, the heat of adsorption is EL is equal to the heat of liquefaction.
> 5. At the saturation pressure, the molecule layer number tends to infinity (i.e. equivalent to the sample being surrounded by a liquid phase)

References: The original [article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01269a023)

P.S: Good reading material on BET theory can be found [here](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/103104045/pdf_version/lecture26.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

My book (G. Wedler, H.-J. Freund, *Lehrbuch der Physikalischen Chemie*, 6. Edition ... obviously a German book on physical chemistry) begins with the following, when introducing the BET equation.

> Besonders bei der Physisorption beobachtet man, dass häufig Adsorption in mehreren Schichten übereinander, eine sog. mehrmolekulare Adsorption eintritt.
>
> *Esp. during physisorption one can observe that often adsorption happens in multiple layers on top of each other, a so called multilayer adsorption occurs.*

Further on it is mentioned that:

> Als ersten gelang es Brunauer, Emmett und Teller, eine für die praktische Anwendung geeignete Adsorptionsisotherme für die Mehrscheichtenadsorption abzuleiten.
>
> *Brunauer, Emmett and Teller were the first who developed a useful adsorption isotherm for practical purposes regarding the multilayer adsorption.*

From that point of view, I would assume, that the BET equation is used for physisorption.

Comment: Wait, just confirming; the Langmuir adsorption isotherm ist für niedriger pressure, right? And it's used in the analysis of Chemisorption?

Comment: a) Please write english and not a mix of different languages. While I understand what you want from me and I really appreciate your wish to use "my" words, that is not helpful for a lot of people. b) Why do you think that?

Comment: Ah, well my German sucks, and I'm trying my best to *practice* using it. Trouble is most of the time I'm not able to form complete sentences in German every time (in this case it's because I don't know what German for 'Pressure' is). Also, my bad, I ended up putting more effort trying to transliterate what I was trying to convey, than in the actual *content* of what I was trying to convey. So correcting that: Langmuir's is for chemisorption at *high* (I know I said *niedriger*, my bad) pressure right?